# Quotient ring Isomorphism in dedekind domain

Tags: ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory, dedekind-domain, cyclotomic-fields, ring-isomorphism

I was reading Jurgen Neukirch and I came across this in lemma $10.1$ and $10.2$

Let $\zeta_n$ be the $n$th root of unity and $n=l^k$, $l$ being a prime, then
$(\lambda)=(1-\zeta_n)$ is a principle ideal and $l\mathcal{O}=(\lambda)^{\phi(n)}$, $\phi$ being the euler totient function. This comes from lemma $10.1$. Then in $10.2$ clearly by applying the fundamental identity, as inertia degree is $1$, $\mathcal{O} /\lambda \mathcal{O} \cong \mathbb{Z}/l\mathbb{Z}$ but then next it says, $\mathcal{O} /\lambda \mathcal{O} \cong \mathbb{Z}/l\mathbb{Z}\Rightarrow \mathcal{O} =\mathbb{Z}+\lambda \mathcal{O} $. Why is this true?

I do not think algebraic number theory is of any use here and it is based on the Isomorphism theorem. Can anyone help?

Comment: Can anyone answer?

Comment: What is unclear to you ? For each $a\in O$ there is some $b\in \Bbb{Z}$ such that $a-b=0\bmod \lambda O$, this is the definition of that the residue classes are represented by integers, so that $a\in \Bbb{Z}+\lambda O$

Comment: How did you deduce For each a∈O there is some b∈Z such that  a−b=0modλO? I mean how is this following from $\mathcal{O} /\lambda \mathcal{O} \cong \mathbb{Z}/l\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: $\mathcal{O} /\lambda \mathcal{O} \cong \mathbb{Z}/l\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: @roydiptajit: the isomorphism $\mathbb{Z}/l\mathbb{Z} \to \mathcal{O}/\lambda\mathcal{O}$ is induced by the composition of the inclusion $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathcal{O}$ with the canonical quotient map $\mathcal{O} \to \to \mathcal{O}/\lambda\mathcal{O}$. In particular, the composition $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathcal{O}/\lambda\mathcal{O}$ is surjective (with kernel $l\mathbb{Z}$), from which it follows that every class in $\mathcal{O}/\lambda\mathcal{O}$ is represented by some element of $\mathbb{Z}$. Now apply reuns' comment.

Comment: Thanks.. Now its clear..

Comment: Just to be clear you surjective argument follows from $\mathcal{O} /\lambda \mathcal{O} \cong \mathbb{Z}/l\mathbb{Z}$ right? @AlexWertheim

Comment: That $ \mathcal{O} /\lambda \mathcal{O} \cong \mathbb{Z}/l\mathbb{Z}$ as groups already implies that $ \mathcal{O} /\lambda \mathcal{O} $ is equal to its subgroup generated by $1$.

Comment: Okay thanks got it..